# Best arguments against title site URLs

Tags: information-architecture

I'm currently working to establish a self service site creation interface for my customer.

The user who is requesting a site can choose a title, template and so forth but the final site URL is handled internally and is represented by a number. For example /sites/000367.

Now the customer argues that he accepts this approach but he still wants to have the site title integrated into the URL like this: /sites/000367HumanRessources

This makes my head ache because it's useless in my opinion. The browser already indexes the history with the title and the end user does not care about which URL is saved in his favourites (or the internal URL in his Sites dashboard). It just gives us developers in the backend more problems to give each site a meaningful ID.

What are the best arguments to convince the customer to not stick to his requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't presume to know what is or isn't useful to the business user. If having the site title in the address bar helps them to do their job more efficiently, then it's a valid request.

If you think that having the title in the address bar creates enough problems for IT that it offsets the value it provides to the business, then by all means argue that from an ROI perspective.

IT exists to serve the business, not the other way around.